# Homework help, Java Pair class

Tags: java, generics

I have a homework assignment to compare a generic Pair that I have created in a class and send it to a tester class for comparison and it should return true. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I think it may be my equals method when trying to compare the two objects. When I think I am on the right track i get StackOverflow exceptions. Here is a portion of my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pair<T1,T2> implements PairInterface<T1,T2>
{
    private T1 aFirst;
    private T2 aSecond;
    Pair p1 = new Pair(aFirst,aSecond);

    public Pair(T1 aFirst, T2 aSecond)
    {

            this.aFirst = aFirst;
            this.aSecond = aSecond;

    }

    /**
     * Gets the first element of this pair.
     * @return the first element of this pair.
     */
    public T1 fst()
    {
        return aFirst;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the second element of this pair.
     * @return the second element of this pair.
     */
    public T2 snd()
    {
        return aSecond;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the first element to aFirst.
     * @param aFirst  the new first element
     */
    public void setFst(T1 aFirst)
    {
        this.aFirst = aFirst;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the second element to aSecond.
     * @param aSecond  the new second element
     */
    public void setSnd(T2 aSecond)
    {
        this.aSecond = aSecond;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether two pairs are equal. Note that the pair
     * (a,b) is equal to the pair (x,y) if and only if a is
     * equal to x and b is equal to y.
     * @return true if this pair is equal to aPair. Otherwise
     * return false.
     */
        @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
    {

        Pair p2 = (Pair) otherObject;

        if(otherObject == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
                if(p1.equals(p2)){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }



        }



    /**
     * Generates a string representing this pair. Note that
     * the String representing the pair (x,y) is "(x,y)". There
     * is no whitespace unless x or y or both contain whitespace
     * themselves.
     * @return a string representing this pair.
     */
        @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return new StringBuilder().append('(').append(fst()).append(',').append(snd()).appen         d(')').toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `p1` for? It is causing your Stack Overflow. Whenever you create a new `Pair` it creates a new `Pair` which creates a new `Pair` etc...

Answer (score 1):

At first, why are you creating a new instance of your class?

```
Pair p1 = new Pair(aFirst,aSecond);
```

You should'n do this, when your object will be created by using constructor, your fields will be initialized.

Second, you have a recursive problem in equals method, it calls equals inside itself.

You've got to change equals method to something like this

```
Pair p2 = (Pair) otherObject;

      if (otherObject == null) {
         return false;
      }

      if (this == otherObject) {
         return true;
      }

      if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass()) {
         return false;
      }

      return this.aFirst.equals(p2.aFirst)
            && this.aSecond.equals(p2.aSecond);
```

Answer (score 0):

`StackOverFlowException` is thrown (most of the times) in recursion (a hint).

Look at your 'equals()` method: you chek if q1.equals(q2). 
equals calls equals... (it will check if q2 equals to q1 using the same method)

To solve it you have to use `equals` method without using 'equals' again inside of it.

**How are we doing it?** 
Well, you want to know if the values in both of the Objects are equal.
You should re-write it and check if the values are equals, not the objects them self, at least not with `equals()`